# C++ enum in .net app crashes

Tags: .net, c++, interop, dllimport

In my C#.Net app I use a C++ DLL with DllImport.
The C++ DLL contains an enum definition:

```
enum mode { A, B, C };

class myClass {
    char name[512];
    mode myMode; //variables beneath this line cause crash
    char pass[512];
};
```

I defined the same `enum` in my C#.Net app:

```
public enum mode { A, B, C };
```

Now if I access a variable of `myclass` that is defined after the `myMode` line, I get a memory corruption error:

```
getName();  //ok
getPass(); //error

extern "C" LPCTSTR FAR PASCAL EXPORT getPass() { return myC->pass; }
```

C# wrapper:

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME)]
public static extern string GetPass();
```

As a workaround I use `int` as type for `myMode` and everything works. But I am curious how to do it right.

Comment: C++ enums are compile-time "fiction" (just like inline functions and templates). After compile time, they are undistinguishable from ints. C++ abstractions are [particularly leaky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Comment: Ew... `char []` in C++ that's really ugly. Btw, may be there is a buffer overflow as the `name` length can be greater than 512. In this case all members after `name` (and `myMode` too) will be corrupted. Just a suggestion without seeing the actual code, though

Comment: @maverik: no buffer overflow. i use simple test values.

Comment: Problem is either in the code you didn't show us or in the import, because the code presented is clear. May be you can show more code, e.g. for `getName()` and `getPass()` methods?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote:

```
// .cpp
extern "C" LPCTSTR FAR PASCAL EXPORT getPass() { return myC->pass; }

// .cs
[DllImport(DLLNAME)]
public static extern string GetPass();
```

Ew... Should this be

```
[DllImport(DLLNAME)]
public static extern string getPass();
```

I don't know whether C# is case-sensitive or not, but AFAIK it is.

Another trick that I can't understand is `LPCTSTR`. Should it be `LPCSTR` because of usage of `char[]`? And, hmm... Does C# really require `PASCAL` convention?

Comment: its an old DLL and i guess FAR and PASCAL aren't necessary any more. I am sorry about the wrong spelling: it should be getPass() in C# and C++. but the problem is not the method. i got at least 20 getter methods with the same signature but only the ones that return content after the mode line crash.

Comment: I have one trick in mind. It would be helpful if you can do the following: declare `mode` as `enum mode { A = 0xFFFFFFF0, B = 0xFFFFFFF1, C = 0xFFFFFFF2 };` and check whether app crashes or not. Don't forget to tell us the results.

Comment: it crashes if i do what you suggest. the funny thing is the getMode() call works but the call of getPass() doesn't. even more strange is the fact that it works depending on the position of mode myMode in my class.